# Returning a refresh token with the resource owner flow

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I have created an authentication server that implements OAuth 2 for authorization and it also provides local password authentication using the resource owner flow.

At the moment I always return a refresh token along with the access token which was an acceptable thing to do when I first implemented the feature. However now I need to implement a remember me feature in the client that uses the server. I could always just save the refresh token in the client when the user ticks the remember me checkbox but the token would still exist on the server and be usable even though the user didn't want it to.

What I want to do is simply pass a parameter along with the request that tells me whether I should create a refresh token or not.

So my question is. Is there some standard or recommended way of doing this using the fields provided in the spec or is it acceptable to simply add a parameter to the request to handle this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no standardized way to choose whether to issue a refresh token or not.